# My Sql Query to get total running hours of a machine when it is in ON condition or in OFF condition

Tags: mysql

Im using Database MySql57. OS- WIN7 . My question is I want to calculate running hours of a machine when it is in ON and OFF condition (**In my table 1 indicates ON and 0 indicates OFF**). I tried but its not accurate . My Table Structure like..

[This is my table and Table name is workshop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8ges.png)

For this i tried a query like

```
SELECT count, min(DATETIME), MAX(DATETIME),
TIMEDIFF((MAX(DATETIME)),(min(DATETIME))) as totalhours
from signode.press1 
WHERE (DateTime between '2017-07-10 00:00:00' and '2017-07-12 00:00:00') AND status='1' group by count
```

But it is not accurate.

Can anyone please help me for this . Im trying this for since 2 days.

Comment: No pictures thanks. Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Guys please any one help me ... Thank you

Comment: I'm not clear what you want. A machine can presumably be on for a period of time then off for a period of time then on then off (and so on) - do you need a duration for each of these blocks? What do you mean by not accurate? Can you also add sample data to your question as text.

Comment: ya  exactly i want the duration that how much time it is ON and OFF between selected DateTime

Comment: Do you want to sum up the count? Why are you grouping the count? According to the image the count in every second is different per line, where the status is on.

Comment: I want total time of machine in ON condition as well as OFF condition. Say for example In my table at particular date (2017-06-30 18:34:55) machine is started and some time machine machine  is OFF at date (2017-06-30 18:35:07) So i want that how much time the machine is ON. i.e, as of My image Machine is ON for about 1 min (00:01:25)approx.

Answer (score 0):

A little messy but given this

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
CREATE TABLE T(ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,TIM DATETIME,STATUS INT);

INSERT INTO T (TIM,STATUS) VALUES
('2017-07-30 07:07:00',1),('2017-07-30 07:08:00',1),('2017-07-30 07:09:00',0),
('2017-07-30 07:10:00',1),('2017-07-30 07:11:00',0),('2017-07-30 07:12:00',0);
```

I would first generate a dummy final status record, generate a block number (for each block of status = 1 and status = 0)  and a sequence number (so that I can join each row to the next row and get a time difference).After that I just need to group and finally sum times.
So this code

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> SELECT X.ID IDX,X.SEQNO SEQNOX,X.TIM TIMX,X.STATUS STATUSX,X.BN BNX
    -> ,Y.ID IDY,Y.SEQNOY,DATE_aDD(Y.TIM, INTERVAL -1 SECOND) TIMY,Y.STATUS STATUSY,Y.BNY
    -> FROM
    -> (
    -> SELECT ID,
    -> @SEQNO:=@SEQNO+1 SEQNO,
    -> TIM,STATUS,
    ->  IF(STATUS <> @P, @BN:=@BN+1,@BN) BN,
    ->  IF(STATUS <> @P, @RN:=1,@RN:=@RN+1) RN,
    ->  @P:=STATUS
    -> FROM
    -> (
    -> SELECT ID,TIM,STATUS
    -> FROM T
    -> UNION SELECT 999999,NOW(),9
    -> ) S
    -> , (SELECT @BN:=0,@RN:=0,@P:=0,@SEQNO:=0) BN
    -> ORDER BY ID
    -> ) X
    ->
    -> JOIN
    ->
    -> (
    -> SELECT ID,
    -> @SEQNOY:=@SEQNOY+1 SEQNOY,
    -> TIM,STATUS,
    ->  IF(STATUS <> @PY, @BNY:=@BNY+1,@BNY) BNY,
    ->  IF(STATUS <> @PY, @RNY:=1,@RNY:=@RNY+1) RNY,
    ->  @PY:=STATUS
    -> FROM
    -> (
    -> SELECT ID,TIM,STATUS
    -> FROM T
    -> UNION SELECT 999999,NOW(),9
    -> ) S
    -> , (SELECT @BNY:=0,@RNY:=0,@PY:=0,@SEQNOY:=0) BNY
    -> ORDER BY ID
    -> ) Y
    -> ON Y.SEQNOY = X.SEQNO + 1;
```

results in

```
+-----+--------+---------------------+---------+------+--------+--------+---------------------+---------+------+
| IDX | SEQNOX | TIMX                | STATUSX | BNX  | IDY    | SEQNOY | TIMY                | STATUSY | BNY  |
+-----+--------+---------------------+---------+------+--------+--------+---------------------+---------+------+
|   1 |      1 | 2017-07-30 07:07:00 |       1 | 1    |      2 |      2 | 2017-07-30 07:07:59 |       1 | 1    |
|   2 |      2 | 2017-07-30 07:08:00 |       1 | 1    |      3 |      3 | 2017-07-30 07:08:59 |       0 | 2    |
|   3 |      3 | 2017-07-30 07:09:00 |       0 | 2    |      4 |      4 | 2017-07-30 07:09:59 |       1 | 3    |
|   4 |      4 | 2017-07-30 07:10:00 |       1 | 3    |      5 |      5 | 2017-07-30 07:10:59 |       0 | 4    |
|   5 |      5 | 2017-07-30 07:11:00 |       0 | 4    |      6 |      6 | 2017-07-30 07:11:59 |       0 | 4    |
|   6 |      6 | 2017-07-30 07:12:00 |       0 | 4    | 999999 |      7 | 2017-07-30 11:31:32 |       9 | 5    |
+-----+--------+---------------------+---------+------+--------+--------+---------------------+---------+------+
6 rows in set (0.12 sec)
```

Then if I wrap this with a group by and sum

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> SELECT STATUSX, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(DIFF)))
    -> FROM
    -> (
    ->
    -> SELECT BNX,STATUSX,MIN(TIMX), MAX(TIMY), TIMEDIFF(MAX(TIMY) , MIN(TIMX)) DIFF
    -> FROM
    -> (
    -> SELECT X.ID IDX,X.SEQNO SEQNOX,X.TIM TIMX,X.STATUS STATUSX,X.BN BNX
    -> ,Y.ID IDY,Y.SEQNOY,DATE_aDD(Y.TIM, INTERVAL -1 SECOND) TIMY,Y.STATUS STATUSY,Y.BNY
    -> FROM
    -> (
    -> SELECT ID,
    -> @SEQNO:=@SEQNO+1 SEQNO,
    -> TIM,STATUS,
    ->  IF(STATUS <> @P, @BN:=@BN+1,@BN) BN,
    ->  IF(STATUS <> @P, @RN:=1,@RN:=@RN+1) RN,
    ->  @P:=STATUS
    -> FROM
    -> (
    -> SELECT ID,TIM,STATUS
    -> FROM T
    -> UNION SELECT 999999,NOW(),9
    -> ) S
    -> , (SELECT @BN:=0,@RN:=0,@P:=0,@SEQNO:=0) BN
    -> ORDER BY ID
    -> ) X
    ->
    -> JOIN
    ->
    -> (
    -> SELECT ID,
    -> @SEQNOY:=@SEQNOY+1 SEQNOY,
    -> TIM,STATUS,
    ->  IF(STATUS <> @PY, @BNY:=@BNY+1,@BNY) BNY,
    ->  IF(STATUS <> @PY, @RNY:=1,@RNY:=@RNY+1) RNY,
    ->  @PY:=STATUS
    -> FROM
    -> (
    -> SELECT ID,TIM,STATUS
    -> FROM T
    -> UNION SELECT 999999,NOW(),9
    -> ) S
    -> , (SELECT @BNY:=0,@RNY:=0,@PY:=0,@SEQNOY:=0) BNY
    -> ORDER BY ID
    -> ) Y
    -> ON Y.SEQNOY = X.SEQNO + 1
    -> ) Z
    ->
    -> GROUP BY STATUSX,BNX
    ->
    -> ) A
    -> GROUP BY STATUSX;
+---------+-------------------------------------+
| STATUSX | SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(DIFF))) |
+---------+-------------------------------------+
|       0 | 04:24:12                            |
|       1 | 00:02:58                            |
+---------+-------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```